# "Approve tag wikis" privilege not granted with exactly 5000 reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, privileges, suggested-edits

Recently, I got to exactly 5000 reputation points. According to the [privileges page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges), this should give me the ability to [approve or reject tag wiki edits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), which was confirmed with "you have already earned this privilege" in the popup:

[image: privileges page with "approve tag wiki edits" tooltip]

However, obviously I didn't receive the privilege, as I still couldn't get access to the [suggested edits page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) (click on the image to see it full-size):

[image: suggested edits page locked with 5000 reputation]

I deleted the temporary data and did a fresh log-on, so this shouldn't be a caching issue.

I was immediately granted the privilege after having *more than* 5000 reputation, so either the algorithm or the description of the privilege seems to be inaccurate: The privileges page suggested that I had already received it. Furthermore, the suggested edits page explicitly states

> [...] When you have earned **at least** 5000 reputation, you will receive the “approve tag wiki edits” privilege and will be allowed to view this page. [emphasis added]

Comment: So there is a `>` instead of a `>=` somewhere in the code? Might be simply by accident. But should be fixed nonetheless.

Comment: I wonder why they don't use the same checks on the [privileges page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges) as they use when you actually try to use the privilege...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tried to repro and couldn't.

Given the age of the question and the number of refactorings we've gone through, my best guess  is that we fixed this sometime in 2013. :-)